# Laravel - LogicException: App\Models\User::token must return a relationship instance, but "null" was returned

Tags: laravel

In Laravel-8, I am creating an end point for ForgotPassword and to also send notification to the user email:

```
public function forgotPassword(ResetPasswordRequest $request)
{
try {
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    if (!$user){
        return $this->error('We can\'t find a user with that e-mail address.', 400);
    }
    $email  =   $request->email;
    $token  =   Str::random(10);

    $passwordReset = PasswordReset::updateOrCreate(
        ['email' => $user->email],
        [
            'email'         =>  $email,
            'token'         =>  $token,
            'created_at'    =>  now()->addHours(10),
         ]
    );

    // Send Email Based on condition
    if ($user && $passwordReset){
        $user->notify(
            new PasswordResetRequest($token)
        );
    }
    return $this->success('We have e-mailed your password reset link!', [
        'user'          => $user,
    ]);
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        Log::error($e);
        return $this->error($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    }
}
```

As I submit, I got this error:

> local.ERROR: LogicException: App\Models\User::token must return a relationship instance, but "null" was returned

When I removed:

```
    if ($user && $passwordReset){
        $user->notify(
            new PasswordResetRequest($token)
        );
    }
```

Notification:

```
class PasswordResetRequest extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    protected $token;
    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
       $url = url('http://localhost:4200/reset-password-submit?token='.$this->token);
        return (new MailMessage)
           ->line('You are receiving this email because we        received a password reset request for your account.')
           ->action('Reset Password', url($url))
           ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
    }
}
```

No error, and it was also inserted into the password_resets table. but I need to send notification.

User and PasswordReset models are not even related.

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: @Professor - Yes. I have use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;  and  use HasApiTokens,

Comment: Is this helpful at all? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passwords#reset-email-customization

Comment: The documentation uses `App\Notifications\ResetPasswordNotification` instead of this `PasswordResetRequest` you're using, which I can guess is a custom Notification. What's in there?

Comment: You could use the `sendPasswordResetNotification` function in the User model if instead of sending the notification from the controller you were just dispatching the `PasswordReset` event: `event(new PasswordReset($user));`. Not sure if that would solve your issue though

Comment: I have updated my code with the Notification.  I'm a bit confused. As you advised, how do I arrange these codes in the model and Controller

Comment: Could you also post the constructor of the Notification?

Comment: @Professor - I have updated the code with the complete notification

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235564/discussion-between-professor-and-user11352561).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like when using `$this->token` in the Notification, you're not getting the PasswordResetRequest $token attribute: you're getting the User Passport Token

Try changing the token variable name to something else.

```php
class PasswordResetRequest extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    protected $url_token;
    public function __construct($url_token)
    {
        $this->url_token = $url_token;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
       $url = url('http://localhost:4200/reset-password-submit?token='.$this->url_token);
       return (new MailMessage)
           ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
           ->action('Reset Password', url($url))
           ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
    }
}
```